# Speed up download Artifacts in Release Management

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a project in TFS that has about 3k files as resulting of the build. What we call artifacts.
It's very frequent I got the status like

```
No download tasks have completed in 1 minutes. Remaining task statuses:
WaitingForActivation: 1 task(s).
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
No download tasks have completed in 2 minutes. Remaining task statuses:
WaitingForActivation: 1 task(s).
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
No download tasks have completed in 3 minutes. Remaining task statuses:
WaitingForActivation: 1 task(s).
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
No download tasks have completed in 4 minutes. Remaining task statuses:
WaitingForActivation: 1 task(s).
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
No download tasks have completed in 5 minutes. Remaining task statuses:
WaitingForActivation: 1 task(s).
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
1 downloads remaining.
No download tasks have completed in 6 minutes. Remaining task statuses:
WaitingForActivation: 1 task(s).
```

I've tried to compress the artifacts and download one single file. But I didn't have success on that.

Could I have a hint from the community about how to speed up the Artifacts download? Is my idea of Archive during build and unzip during release a good approach?

I've tried that but I wasn't able to download only the zip file created.

Comment: Hi CraySpy, any update on this? Did my reply helped or gave a right direction?

Answer (score 2):

> We have started using robocopy to download build artifacts in recent
>   version of vsts-agent. Download performance using robocopy should be
>   better than the performance with v1 agent as well. In case upgrading
>   to TFS 2018 is not a viable solution, pl. get latest agent from here
>   and configure against TFS server:
>
> https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/releases

If you are not using TFS2018, suggest you use the latest build agent which will use robocopy should be better performance.

Another option is zipping or creating a nuget package for each public artifact and then after the drop, unzipping. You could use [Archive Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=vsts) task or some 3rd-party extension in marketplace. Take a look at below two related question:

- [TFS build v2 agent downloads artifacts slowly, v1 unaffected](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/77641/tfs-build-v2-agent-downloads-artifacts-slowly-v1-u.html)
- [VSTS agent very slow to download artifacts from local network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44955961/vsts-agent-very-slow-to-download-artifacts-from-local-network-share)

Besides, Release Management downloads all the artifacts published by the build definition that you selected by default before. Now you are able to add a configuration option for a release definition to force agents to only download artifacts that are required for task execution. This will also speed up your release pipeline. *Note:* This is only available to the on-prem version in TFS 2018 Update 2.

Details please take a look at this blog: [Speed up your VSTS Releases by Partially Downloading Artifacts](http://www.deliveron.com/blog/speed-your-vsts-releases-partially-downloading-artifacts/)